# swift 1.2 collection view

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

I've got this simple code to control Collection view, but it doesn't show any cells. The app works, but it's blank. The identifier match with cell identifier and the class is attached to the collection view. 
I think the problem is with upcast: as! UICollectionViewCell

```
class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {
     var Array = ["one", "two"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
         super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }
    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
          return Array.count
   }

   override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell
        return cell
   }
}
```

Comment: You should fill the content after `let cell = collectionView....`

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention, I changed the color of the cells also tried to add label, but the cells doesn't show, it's just blank

Comment: What is `itemSize` set to in your storyboard?  Also, just a guess but does adding `collectionView.reloadData()` in viewDidLoad help?

Comment: itemSize is 1 and reloadData didn't help

Answer (score 0):

may be you forgot to check the **as initial view controller** option from storyboard...

[image]

In the right side panel under **View Controller** just below the title, there is a checkbox **as Initial View controller**, tick this and then try to run...

Comment: are you using your own custom CollectionviewCell class??

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your overriding of `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:` is not returning `0`.

Comment: Well, he returns `Array.count` which 2, but he does not fill in the cell.

Comment: ["If you do not implement this method, the collection view uses a default value of 1."](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDataSource_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDataSource/numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:)

Comment: @ThomasKilian he's returning Array.count on items in section, not in sections in collection.

Comment: @Brian, I know, but he might had overriden the method (boilerplate code from xcode?) and is returning 0, he just didnt post it here

Comment: even if I return 1 section it still doesn't show the cells